# While copying, Ubuntu 18.04 is detecting directory to be much larger than it is

Tags: partitioning, mount, files, disk, copy

This question is not about why the file sizes mentioned by different commands in Ubuntu aren't exactly the same (e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280342/)). On the contrary, it says they are almost same. It's about why the copy command thinks a folder is ~711GB instead of the purported ~140GB.

A 1 TB HDD containing folder `folder` is mounted at `/media/username/drivename`. 
The folder size as determined to be ~130-140GB using 3 separate methods. ( `df`, folder properties, Disk Usage Analyzer utility), however upon trying to copy `folder` to `/home/username/Desktop`(present on a separate boot drive SSD) the operating system says that there isn't enough available disk space in the SSD.

```
273.2 GB more space is required to copy to the destination.
```

This error occurs when the 'copy progress' popup is at:

```
Preparing to copy 2859633 files(438.5GB)
```

i.e the system reports `folder` is ~711GB.

Specs:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- SSD: 256GB available disk space, ~251GB Total (according to Disk Usage Analyzer)
- HDD: 1TB available disk space, ~983GB Total (according to Disk Usage Analyzer)
  update: `ls -l folder` lists `drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root` for everything inside

The ultimate goal is to make a 700GB partition on the HDD to install CentOS and then copy `folder` back into the remaining space where it will keep getting used by the backup software running on Ubuntu 18.04 which is installed on an SSD.

Comment: found a solution for the ultimate goal (shrinking the drive so that the smaller partition automatically contains `folder`)...but the original question stays open

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does ls -l output a different size from ls -s?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269480/why-does-ls-l-output-a-different-size-from-ls-s) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280342/why-do-df-and-du-commands-show-different-disk-usage)