# `ls -l` output duration instead of date/time eg "5 mins"/"6 hours"/"7 days" etc?

Tags: command-line, bash, time, ls

If I last modified a file 5 minutes ago, is it possible to make `ls-l` output something like "5 mins" instead of the actual date/time?

Comment: [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Formatting-file-timestamps.html#Formatting-file-timestamps) you will find some useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here because this is what I actually ended up doing.

I could not get any satisfactory results using anything that parsed the output of `ls -l` into a word stream (`bash`, `awk`, `column` etc) because a) filenames with spaces in messed up, and b) `ls -l`'s aligned columns messed up (for example, right-aligned filesizes). `ls -l | column -t` shows both problems at once.

I will get shot down for the inefficiency in this, but this is my eventual script that uses `sed` to replace parts of the output of `ls -l` maintaining column width:

```
day0=`date                     +"%b %_d"`
day1=`date --date "1 day  ago" +"%b %_d"`
day2=`date --date "2 days ago" +"%b %_d"`
day3=`date --date "3 days ago" +"%b %_d"`
day4=`date --date "4 days ago" +"%b %_d"`
day5=`date --date "5 days ago" +"%b %_d"`
day6=`date --date "6 days ago" +"%b %_d"`

min0=`date                        +"%H:%M"`
min1=`date --date "1 minute  ago" +"%H:%M"`
min2=`date --date "2 minutes ago" +"%H:%M"`
min3=`date --date "3 minutes ago" +"%H:%M"`
min4=`date --date "4 minutes ago" +"%H:%M"`
min5=`date --date "5 minutes ago" +"%H:%M"`
min6=`date --date "6 minutes ago" +"%H:%M"`
min7=`date --date "7 minutes ago" +"%H:%M"`
min8=`date --date "8 minutes ago" +"%H:%M"`
min9=`date --date "9 minutes ago" +"%H:%M"`

ls -lh --color=force --quoting-style=shell-escape "$@"|sed "\
  /$day6 \(.[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)/ s/$day6/6 days/; t
  /$day5 \(.[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)/ s/$day5/5 days/; t
  /$day4 \(.[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)/ s/$day4/4 days/; t
  /$day3 \(.[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)/ s/$day3/3 days/; t
  /$day2 \(.[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)/ s/$day2/2 days/; t
  /$day1 \(.[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)/ s/$day1/yesday/; t
  /$day0 \(.[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)/ s/$day0/ today/; T
  s/$min0/  now/; t
  s/$min1/1 min/; t
  s/$min2/2 min/; t
  s/$min3/3 min/; t
  s/$min4/4 min/; t
  s/$min5/5 min/; t
  s/$min6/6 min/; t
  s/$min7/7 min/; t
  s/$min8/8 min/; t
  s/$min9/9 min/; t
  "
```

Sample output of `/var/log/syslog*`:

```
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm    9240  today   now /var/log/syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 1279965  today 8 min /var/log/syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   51750 2 days 14:12 /var/log/syslog.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   14768 3 days 10:59 /var/log/syslog.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm    7767 4 days 10:04 /var/log/syslog.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  119295 5 days 09:49 /var/log/syslog.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   33450 6 days 13:06 /var/log/syslog.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm   21372 Jan 25 11:12 /var/log/syslog.7.gz
```

(not sure why log appears here in red; it doesn't on my terminal.)

This is only used from the command line so all those `date` commands don't matter, in fact I don't notice any delay at all.

Update:

`time` output for `ls -l /var/log/syslog*':

```
real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.000s
```

`time` output for for my new script:

```
real    0m0.019s
user    0m0.018s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Answer (score 1):

I use stat to get metadata info on the files. Some examples:

```
stat -c $'%y\t%n' * | sort -n
```

Output looks like this:

```
2020-01-27 11:52:25.681249958 +0200 CHANGELOG.md
```

Then to lookup a single file

```
stat CHANGELOG.md
```

and output looks like this:

```
  File: CHANGELOG.md
  Size: 94          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
  Device: fd00h/64768d  Inode: 6029378     Links: 1
  Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  998/example)   Gid: (  998/example)
  Access: 2020-11-12 17:47:34.768793021 +0200
  Modify: 2020-01-27 11:52:25.681249958 +0200
  Change: 2020-11-12 17:47:02.282093672 +0200
  Birth: -
```

Otherwise you might need a small bash script to show you the difference between when the file was created and current time.

```
 LastUpdate="$(stat -c %Y myfile)"
 now="$(date +%s)"
 let diff="${now}-${lastUpdate}"
```

Comment: You can use `$EPOCHSECONDS` shell variable instead of `$(date +%s)`

Comment: Only in bash 5 and later - 18.04 LTS is on bash 4.4, 20.04 LTS is bash 5.

Answer (score 1):

This is a continuation of an earlier [script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1185414/986805) used for parsing
 `ls -l` with some enhancement:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while read -r p c u g s e n; do
    [[ $p = total ]] && { \
        echo "$p $c" 1>&2; continue; \
    }
    x=$(($EPOCHSECONDS - e))
    y=$((x / 60))
    z=$((x % 60))
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' \
            "$p" \
            "$c" \
            "$u" \
            "$g" \
            "$s" \
            "$y minutes" \
            "$z seconds" \
            "$n"
done < <( \
    ls -LApl --color=force \
             --time-style=+%s \
             --quoting-style=shell-escape "$@" \
) \
| column -t -R 2,5,6,7 -s $'\t' -o ' '
```

Comment: Thank you it hadn't occured to me that you could parse the output of `ls -l` in bash so easily. I already have a bash function that outputs a duration in seconds in the format I like, so I will start from this. `$EPOCHSECONDS` doesn't work for me though on 18.04 (bash 4.4) but I can use the appropriate `date` command.

Comment: @B.Tanner think `x=$(($(printf '%(%s)T') - e))` is a better choice than `date`

Comment: `printf` has the advantage of being builtin.

Comment: On my system (18.04 kubuntu) `which printf` shows an execuable at /usr/bin/printf, and `which date` shows an executable at /bin/date, whereas `which cd` and `which shopt` do not produce an output (and return an error code of 1). But date is 99k and printf is 51k :-O

Comment: I think the order is alias, keyword, function, builtin, and file. but I'm not really sure. You can use `type printf`, builtin has the advantage of not needing any load time. `time (printf '%(%s)T')` vs `time (date +%s)`

Comment: think `pico /usr/bin/which` is an ordinary shell script, only searching the PATH.

Comment: Ah thank you...'type'! I wonder why printf is there on $PATH as an exectable file too then? I suppose non-bash shells might not have it as a builtin?

Answer (score 0):

**One way:**

You can make `ls` print modification time in seconds since epoch, like so:

```
ls -l --time-style="+%s"
```

Then pipe the `ls` output to `awk` to do the logic, like so:

```
ls -l --time-style="+%s" | awk -v now=$(date +%s) '{$6 = now - $6; d=int($6/60/60/24); h=int($6/60/60%24); m=int($6/60%60); s=int($6%60);$6 = "="d" Days "h" Hours "m" Mins "s" Secs ago="; print}' | column -t -s'='
```

Because the command line is long, here is a break-up which is basically the same but can be visually more contained:

```
ls -l --time-style="+%s" | \
awk -v now=$(date +%s) '{\
$6 = now - $6; \
d=int($6/60/60/24); \
h=int($6/60/60%24); \
m=int($6/60%60); \
s=int($6%60);\
$6 = "="d" Days "h" Hours "m" Mins "s" Secs ago="; print}' | column -t -s'='
```

- `-v now=$(date +%s)` will assign the current time in seconds since epoch to `now`
- `$6 = now - $6` will calculate the time in seconds since file last modified.
- `d=int($6/60/60/24)` will calculate the days.
- `h=int($6/60/60%24)` will calculate remaining hours less than one day.
- `m=int($6/60%60)` will calculate remaining minutes less than one hour.
- `s=int($6%60)` will calculate remaining seconds less than one minute.
- `$6 = d" Days "h" Hours "m" Mins "s" Secs ago"` will change the modification date to something like **2 Days 5 Hours 3 Mins 47 Secs ago**.

---

**Another way:**

You can construct your own custom `ls -l` alternative in a bash script, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *
        do
        p=$(stat -c "%A=%h=%U=%G=%s" "$f")
        m=$(date -r "$f" "+%s")
        n=$(date "+%s")
        l=$((n-m))
        d=$((l/60/60/24))
        h=$((l/60/60%24))
        m=$((l/60%60))
        s=$((l%60))
        echo "$p= = =$d Days=$h Hours=$m Mins=$s=Secs= = =$f" | column -t -s'='
        done
```

or make the output simpler and less time strict, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *
        do
        p=$(stat -c "%A %h %U %G %s" "$f")
        m=$(date -r "$f" "+%s")
        n=$(date "+%s")
        l=$((n-m))
        d=$((l/60/60/24))
        h=$((l/60/60%24))
        m=$((l/60%60))
        s=$((l%60))
        if (( $d >= 1 ))
                then
                t="$d Days"
        elif (( $h >= 1 ))
                then
                t="$h Hours"
        elif (( $m >= 1 ))
                then
                t="$m Mins"
        else
                t="$s Secs"
        fi 
        echo "$p= = =$t= = =$f" | column -t -s'='
        done
```

---

**Notice on usage:**

If you save **either** the above command **or** the above script in a file in your *home directory*, name the file `lsl.sh` and make it executable like so:

```
chmod +x ~/lsl.sh
```

you can add an alias like this:

```
alias lsl='bash ~/lsl.sh'
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file so you can afterwords run the short command:
`

```
lsl
```

from any directory and get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you... to bash or awk?! I am going to run with bash for now because I am more familiar with bash than awk.

Comment: @B.Tanner I updated the answer with alternative bash script.